# mysql dynamic queries execution

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to write MySQL script dropping some tables selected by pattern but my procedure doesn't compile. Could anybody please advice what is wrong with it please?

```
delimiter #
drop procedure if exists drop_audit_tables #
create procedure drop_audit_tables()
begin
  declare done int default false;
  declare cmd varchar(4000);
  declare cmds cursor for select 'drop table [' + table_name + ']' from information_schema.tables where table_name like '%_audit';
  declare continue handler for not found set done = true;
  open cmds;
  tLoop: loop
    fetch cmds into cmd;
    if done then
      leave tLoop;
    end if;
    PREPARE STMT FROM cmd;
    EXECUTE STMT;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;
  end loop tLoop;
  close cmds;
end #
```

the error message:

[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cmd; EXECUTE STMT; DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT; end loop tLoop; close cm' at line 13

Comment: I have never used cursors, but I can say that `PREPARE STMT FROM cmd;` might fail if `cmd` is not a string that represents a valid SQL command. I see your `fetch cmds into cmd;` line, but is that really a good idea? Does that line actually put a SQL command into `cmd`, or the *result set* of the third `declare` statement. Just trying to help. Anthony.

Comment: I might wait to change the delimiter after running `drop procedure if exists drop_audit_tables`.

Comment: Where is `[' + table_name + ']'` coming from? Where is table_name coming from?

Comment: Assuming that table_name is the dynamic part of your prepared statement. But, again, where is `table_name` coming from?

Comment: You are using sql server syntax in some places [' + table_name + ']'

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
declare cmds cursor for select 'drop table [' + table_name + ']' from information_schema.tables where table_name like '%_audit';
```

.. uses `table_name` without defining it first.

Try defining it first with something like:

```
create procedure drop_audit_tables(IN table_name VARCHAR(64))
```

You may want to consider the security implications of taking a variable directly from the stored procedure and placing it into your ad-hoc query. 
Still, define `table_name` somewhere. In this case `table_name` would be supplied as an argument to your stored procedure. Your task then is to gather an array of table names and run this code in a for/foreach loop.

## Basic (non-robust) PHP (PDO)

```
/* Get the audit tables. */
$stmt   = $pdo->query(`CALL get_audit_tables()`)
$tables = $stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close()

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('CALL drop_audit_tables(:table)')

/* Drop each audit table. */
foreach($tables as $table)
{
    $stmt->bindParam(:table, $table, PDO::PARAM_STR)
    $stmt->execute();
}

$stmt->close();
```

Something like that, anyway.

> [MySQL: CREATE PROCEDURE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html)
>
> Specifying a parameter as IN, OUT, or INOUT is valid only for a PROCEDURE. For a FUNCTION, parameters are always regarded as IN parameters.
>
> [PHP Manual: PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)
>
> Prepares an SQL statement to be executed by the PDOStatement::execute() method. The SQL statement can contain zero or more named (:name) or question mark (?) parameter markers for which real values will be substituted when the statement is executed.

A solution like this would make your life easier. You only need to define a basic query that finds your audit tables. Less code. Simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the cursor:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `one_audit`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `two_audit`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `three_audit`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `one_audit`(`a` INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `two_audit`(`a` INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `three_audit`(`a` INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @`drop_tables` := (
    ->   SELECT
    ->     CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ',
    ->     GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', `TABLE_NAME`, '`') SEPARATOR ', '))
    ->   FROM
    ->     `information_schema`.`TABLES`
    ->   WHERE
    ->     `TABLE_SCHEMA` = DATABASE() AND
    ->     `TABLE_TYPE` = 'BASE TABLE' AND
    ->     `TABLE_NAME` LIKE '%_audit'
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @`drop_tables`;
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| @`drop_tables`                                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `one_audit`, `three_audit`, `two_audit` |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE `exec` FROM @`drop_tables`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE `exec`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE `exec`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

You must be careful with the system variable [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len).

**UPDATE**

Using cursor:

```sql
DELIMITER #

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `drop_audit_tables`#

CREATE PROCEDURE `drop_audit_tables`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE `done` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE `cmd` VARCHAR(4000);
  DECLARE `cmds` CURSOR FOR
  SELECT
    CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `', `TABLE_NAME`, '`')
  FROM
    `information_schema`.`TABLES`
  WHERE
    `TABLE_SCHEMA` = DATABASE() AND
    `TABLE_TYPE` = 'BASE TABLE' AND
    `TABLE_NAME` LIKE '%_audit';
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET `done` := 1;

  OPEN `cmds`;

  `tLoop`: LOOP
    FETCH `cmds` INTO `cmd`;
    IF `done` THEN
      CLOSE `cmds`;
      LEAVE `tLoop`;
    END IF;
    SET @`cmd` := `cmd`;
    PREPARE `STMT` FROM @`cmd`;
    EXECUTE `STMT`;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE `STMT`;
  END LOOP `tLoop`;

  SET @`cmd` := NULL;
END#

CALL `drop_audit_tables`#

DELIMITER ;
```

> [14.5.1 PREPARE
>   Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html)
>
> PREPARE ***stmt_name*** FROM ***preparable_stmt***
>
> ...
>
> ***preparable_stmt*** is either a string literal or a user variable that
>   contains the text of the SQL statement.
>
> ...

Comment: I would only ask where the first ``TABLE_NAME`` reference is coming from that allows it to be concatenated.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge: Column `TABLE_NAME` from `TABLES` table. `SELECT \`TABLE_NAME\` FROM \`information_schema\`.\`TABLES\`;`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge: `The TABLES table provides information about tables in databases.`. See [22.24 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html).

Comment: Looking here, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat, but not seeing how it is going to provide the table names as you say. There is no aggregate function operation. I guess you know more than me.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge: The following example may help. [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d9a3/2).

Comment: I see. Interesting. But, this  a lot just to drop some tables.